# Reading continuous data flow from serial port and deserialize JSON objects

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, uwp

In an UWP app I want to read a continuous data flow from a serial port. The inputstream contains continuous json objects like this:

```
{
  "sensor": "gps",
  "time": 1351824120,
  "data": [
    48.75608,
    2.302038
  ]
}

{
  "sensor": "gps",
  "time": 1351824120,
  "data": [
    48.75608,
    2.302038
  ]
}

{
  "sensor": "gps",
  "time": 1351824120,
  "data": [
    48.75608,
    2.302038
  ]
} 

...
```

For listening on the port, I'm using

`var dataReaderObject = new DataReader(SerialPort.InputStream);`.

I'm using also a task to wait for data on the serialPort.InputStream.

```
Task<UInt32> loadAsyncTask = dataReaderObject.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength);
```

But the problem is, I don't know the length of one JSON object. How can read or buffer the stream, so that I can desirialize the JSON stream? Something like `load data from "{" to "}"` .

Is there any best practice to do that?

**EDIT:**

I can also influence the data sending side. Maybe it is better to send the serali data in a better format? Do you have any suggestions to improve the sent data?

Comment: If you can influence the sending side, why not just include the length of the JSON that is going to be sent?

Comment: @WiredPrairie The JSON is sent until the device is shutdown. I don't know the length in advance. I could send the length of each single JSON object. But then I also have to read this "length value". How would I do that?

Comment: If you can't do that, you'll need to build a state machine basically to continually concatenate the results until you detect a marker of some sort (which could have been length, but also could be blank lines, etc.).

Comment: I'm fighting with the same issue on Raspberry Pi and Windows IoT Core. The simplest solution that i could imagine is to set a value of ReadBufferLength to 1 and compare each value to some marker. In my case I have a JSON arrays coming from another device and I try to compare current buffer value with "]" character to determine the end of stream. But my application throws exceptions when trying to use such buffer (it doesnt display any details about this exception). Do you have any success with your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  can do this by Counting the total number of '{'  braces and the total number of  '}' braces .

Step 1: Declare an integer to store the count.

Step 2: Now increment the integer as soon as u encounter a '{'

Step 3: Decrease the integer as soon as u encounter a '}'

Step 4: When the counter goes 0 get the character position and get the sub string from the string by using start and end positions. (That's the JSON u want).

Step 5: Deserialize the Json.

Comment: Ok, when should I do that, after LoadAsync?

Comment: Yes , Read the buffer and if you are finished with the counter before the buffer ends.. make sure to store the remaining string in another buffer and and add it to the incoming buffer

Answer (score 1):

The stream includes a blank line between objects. So, look for two consecutive line breaks, and parse up to that point.

Comment: And at which point would I do that? Before LoadAsync? Do you have an example or can you point me to an similiar example?